# Set Data Validation on cell based on dropdown from another cell Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have two columns in excel sheet, the first one is `bankName` and it's a dropdown of bank names, and `bankAccountNumber` the user will write the account number based on the bank name he/she choose.

[image]

If the user selects `HSBC` bank i wanna add data validation on the adjacent cell to have length to 12, and whenever he selects another bank i want to change the adjacent cell validation and so on.

I can't change the  data validation dynamically like what i want so if anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses **structured reference table**.

Suppose you have a table called `Tbl_Len` showing the length of account number for each bank such as below:

[image: Tbl_Len]

Suppose your result table is called **Tbl_AN** such as below:

[image: Tbl_AN]

Then you need to set up a **named range** called `Len_Check` using the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(Tbl_AN[@[Bank Name]],Tbl_Len[Bank],Tbl_Len[Acct No Length])
```

If your version of Excel cannot use the **XLOOKUP** function, you can use **INDEX+MATCH** to achieve the same:

```
=INDEX(Tbl_Len[Acct No Length],MATCH(Tbl_AN[@[Bank Name]],Tbl_Len[Bank],0))
```

[image: Named Range]

Highlight the `Account Number` column in the `Tbl_AN` table, set up the data validation as below:

[image: Data Validation]

Then a warning will pop out each time you enter an accountant number with the wrong length such as below (you can DIY the warning message as desired):

[image: Warning]

Let me know if there is any question :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But what if the validation not limited to length only, I want to check dashes between numbers, and more than one length is allowed

Comment: @Zeyad Etman Then you probably need VBA that I cannot assist.